# Columns getting resized to big width automatically after some columns are hidden in Slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have custom code to hide columns, where I set their max width to 1.
After hiding multiple columns in this way, when I try to resize the left most columns, their width increase automatically to a large value, as soon as I click to resize, without dragging. Then this large width becomes the min width of the column, and I am not able to make the column smaller than that.
After looking around, I found that `setupColumnResize()` function of slick.grid.js `shrinkLeewayOnRight = 100000;` `shrinkLeewayOnLeft = 100000;` `stretchLeewayOnRight = 100000;` `stretchLeewayOnLeft = 100000;` seems to be causing the issue.

If I resize this, then the headers and columns get misaligned.

Kindly help and suggest a solution where the size of the columns doesn't increase so much and it can be reduced.

My code to hide/show columns : If check box is checked : column visible else not visible

```js
if (document.getElementById(temp).checked == false) {

    columns[i].cssClass = "reallyHidden";
    columns[i].headerCssClass = "reallyHidden";
    columns[i].maxWidth = 1;
    var classString = columns[i].name + "_class";
    var widthString = columns[i].name + "_width";
    localStorage.setItem(classString, "reallyHidden");
    localStorage.setItem(widthString, "1");
   // localStorage.setItem(columns[i].name, columns[i].minWidth);

}


if (document.getElementById(temp).checked == true) {
        var classString = columns[i].name + "_class";
        if (localStorage.getItem(classString) != null) {
        columns[i].cssClass = null
        columns[i].headerCssClass = null
        columns[i].maxWidth = null;
        
        var widthString = columns[i].name + "_width";
        localStorage.setItem(classString, "null");
        localStorage.setItem(widthString, "null");
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help to use jsfiddle with your HTML.

Comment: if you're using the `6pack/SlickGrid` fork, it might be caused by the new auto-size column as mentioned in this [Auto Column Sizing - Wiki](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Auto-Column-Sizing)